# C# How to have a shape follow cursor position

Tags: c#, canvas

Is there a way to use the GetLastMousePositionScaled(out Point) method to have a shape follow the cursor? This is what I have so far:

```
               Canvas.GetLastMousePositionScaled(out Point mousePosition);

               Canvas.AddRectangle(mousePosition.X, mousePosition.Y, Color.Blue);
               
               Canvas.Render();
```

I tried the above code, but it erased everything I already had on my canvas

Answer (score 0):

It may be the Scaled position that is not allowing the canvas to properly render your point.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The *answer* is unclear?  Seriously?  How about the question?  The bot needs work